# How to edit cookies

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

```
async def get_request(url, data=None, json=None, proxy=None, timeout=180):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            async with session.get(
                url,
                data=data,
                json=json,
                proxy=proxy,
                timeout=timeout,
            ) as r:
                return await r.text()
        except BaseException as e:
            raise e
```

Hey guys, I am using this function in my project, but I need to edit one value in cookie. I have tried to add 
`aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=cookies)` and write `cookies = {'topiclist': '123'}`
What I am doing wrong?
I have read documentation and spend half day trying different things, but no result.
I have already read the documentation, give me an advice please or the answer how can I solve the problem, I have never worked with cookies before so maybe I am doing some silly things, do not judge me strictly .